# Проебразования массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, динамические-массивы

Всем привет,
У меня есть вот такой вот массив.

```
[
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

Как сделать так что-бы, например при нажатие на позицию [0][4] все ячейки где 0 преоброзовались в "show", с условием что они ограничены числами которые не ровны 0.
Вот таким образом

```
[
 [1, 1, 1, 'show', 'show', 'show', 'show', 'show', 'show']
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 'show', 'show']
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

Comment: это реализация сапера?

Comment: да, но с колхозным кодом :)

Comment: у каждой ячейки есть 4 соседа. Открыв ячейку - идешь открывать соседние, если там 0 - повторяшь все заново

Comment: @Grundy прошу прощение , можешт пж сказать как называется события когда держишь клик на элемент, не onmouseup а протиположное :)

Comment: `onmousedown` - up -> down

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое

Comment: @Grundy можно хотя-бы пример кода как это +/- сделать, вариантов совсем нет

Comment: `function open(cell){ if (cell.value == 0) { for each neighbour: open(neighbour)} }`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const gameMap = [
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
  [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
];

function open(x, y) {
  if (x === gameMap.length || y === gameMap[0].length || y === -1 || x === -1 || gameMap[x][y] === 'show') {
    return;
  }

  if (gameMap[x][y] === 0) {
    gameMap[x][y] = 'show';

    const neiborhood = [{
        a: x,
        b: y + 1
      },
      {
        a: x + 1,
        b: y
      },
      {
        a: x,
        b: y - 1
      },
      {
        a: x - 1,
        b: y
      }
    ];

    neiborhood.forEach((item) => {
      open(item.a, item.b)
    })
  } else {
    alert('You loose!');
  }
}

open(0, 4);
console.log(gameMap);
```

Comment: За что минус, не понятно. Написал код в свое удовольствие, который решает вопрос. Если есть претензии, то можно и попросить пояснить. Ох уж эти безжалостные минусаторы)

Comment: сошласен, они меня тоже бесят